Execute init routine in GitLab job service container if it requires content of the build directory
GitLab job services can access the build directory of the job container. However, service containers are started before the job container. What if my service needs to perform some bootstrapping logic requiring the content of the build directory? How to trigger it?
I came up with several ideas how to do that, but I don't really like them. The simplest is to check for some kind of flag file to be present in the build directory and once it's there to trigger the init routine. However, if I do that the job container may start using the service when it's not yet ready. So I'd need to make the job container wait for the service to be initialized. It's all doable, but I'd like to have more elegant solution.
UPD: I have figured it out myself. Here's the solution I found.
One sentence description. Let's do nothing during service container initialization and trigger it from the job service using SSH.
Short description. Let's install SSH server in service container. When the job service is ready send a command(s) to the service container which will perform all bootstrapping logic. Then execute the rest of the job commands.
Detailed description.
SSH keys. Generate private and public key pair using keygen command. Store this in your repository (you may skip this and instead copy/paste the key files content right into the job script).
Prepare docker file to build service container: install openssh-server, allow root login with public key, and add the generated public key to the authorized keys. Example:
FROM ubuntu:jammy

# === INSTALL SSH server ===

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server && \
    mkdir /var/run/sshd && \
    sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \
    sed -i 's/#PubkeyAuthentication yes/PubkeyAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \
    mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    echo -n "ssh-rsa <YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY>" | cat > /root/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    chmod 700 /root/.ssh && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]

Prepare docker file to build job container: install openssh-client and create a folder to store public and private keys (you could as well add the keys right here). Example:
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

# === INSTALL SSH client ===

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-client && \
    mkdir -p /root/.ssh && chmod 700 /root/.ssh

Build and push the images to GitLab container registry. First, login to GitLab container registry, for instance with personal access token. Then run the script:
#!/bin/bash

#build service image
docker build -t <TAG> <PATH_TO_DOCKER_FILE>
#push service image
docker push <SERVICE_IMAGE_REGISTRY_PATH>

#build job image
docker build -t <TAG> <PATH_TO_DOCKER_FILE>
#push job image
docker push <JOB_IMAGE_REGISTRY_PATH>

Define GitLab job. Use docker images from GitLab container registry, set FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD variable to 1, copy key pair from repository folder to /root/.ssh folder. Example:
my-job:
  stage: my-stage
  image: <JOB_IMAGE_REGISTRY_PATH>
  services:
    - name: <SERVICE_IMAGE_REGISTRY_PATH>
      alias: srv
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1
  before_script:
    - cp <PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY_IN_REPOSITORY> /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    - cp <PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY_IN_REPOSITORY> /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    - chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@srv '<SERVICE_INIT_COMMANDS>'
    - <JOB_COMMANDS>

